# RegExp Headache for mixed text/digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing 'mustache light' templating with the data coming out of a database with Javascript.  The data looks like this:

> As you can see in {{Figure 1-1}}, and again in {{Figures 1-2}} and {{1-3}}, the hozzfrazz is much cleaner than the hooble stick.

My regexp is `\{\{[-a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\}\}/gi`, which to my mind captures all of the above mustaches.  But the only one being recognized in my function is `{{1-3}}`, not the other two.

Any help?

Apparently I need to add my function as well, since the regex works:

```
var mReg = new RegExp("\{\{[-a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\}\}");
var link_tpl = "<a href='#' rel='@$' class='questionImageLink'>@@</a>";
var html = ''; 
var i = 1;
while (mReg.test(mText) === true) {
    mText = mText.replace(mReg, function (f) {
        var inner = f.substr(2, f.indexOf("}") - 2);
        return link_tpl.replace("@@", inner).replace("@$", i);
    }, "g");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It works for me if you remember to include the opening delimiter `/` http://jsfiddle.net/JYrhm/

Comment: are you sure? It seems to match all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/4wyGG/

Comment: Are you using `exec` ? Remember to `while` whilst doing it and not after.

Comment: Added my js since the regexp is apparently not the issue.

Comment: @b.e.hollenbeck: In a regex constructor you have to double-escape special characters, use a literal regex instead, plus you don't have the global flag...

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to increment `i` as well.

Comment: Check my answer, that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this, using a more forgiving regex and `replace` instead of the `while` mess.

```
var re = /\{\{([^{}]+)\}\}/g;
var results = [];

str.replace( re, function(a, b) { results.push(b); });

console.log(results); //=> ['Figure 1-1', 'Figures 1-2', '1-3']
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fE3U3/