# Getting wrapped strings using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider following sting:

```
'aaa (d) ddd (xc) '
```

How I get following result using just match function:

```
["d","xc"]
```

I tried `'aaa (d) ddd (xc) '.match(/\(.*?\)/g)` but it returns:`["(d)","(xc)"]`

Comment: As a side note, why don't you use a regex similar to this: `\((.*?)\)`?

Comment: @Blender Because it returns `["(d)", "d"]`

Comment: @Reza: Not possible, since JS doesn't have look behind. To return "d" and "xc", the bracket must not be consumed as part of the match, but you still need to assert the opening bracket, so it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking a bit Korikulum's regex...

If instead of anything `.*` specified anything that is not opening bracket:

```
'aaa (d) ddd (xc) (more) text'.match(/[^\(]+(?=\))/g) // >> ["d", "xc", "more"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript doesn't support look behind you could do this:

```
var a = 'aaa (d) ddd (xc)'.match(/\(.*?(?=\))/g);

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  a[i] = a[i].slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `replace` instead of `match`. I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243292/regexp-headache-for-mixed-text-digits/13243515#13243515) today:

```
var str = 'aaa (d) ddd (xc)', 
    results = [];
str.replace(/\(([^()]+)\)/g, function(a,b) { results.push(b) });

console.log(results); //=> ['d', 'xc']
```